How do I submit a background job without the spool printing?
Here is an outline of my code that submits a background job:
 CALL FUNCTION 'JOB_OPEN'
    EXPORTING
      jobname          = v_jobname
      sdlstrtdt        = sy-datum
      sdlstrttm        = sy-uzeit
    IMPORTING
      jobcount         = v_jobcount.

  SUBMIT (gc_report) AND RETURN
  USING SELECTION-SET gc_variant
  WITH SELECTION-TABLE t_seltab
  USER sy-uname
  VIA JOB v_jobname
  NUMBER v_jobcount.

CALL FUNCTION 'JOB_CLOSE'
  EXPORTING
    jobcount             = v_jobcount
    jobname              = v_jobname
    strtimmed            = abap_true.

The users have default printers which are required for other tasks:

So when this code runs it automatically prints the spool to their default printer.
How can I change my SUBMIT statement to stop the spool being printed but still keep it viewable in SM37? I found one way to do it which was to submit the report using a system user but some users don't have the authorisations to schedule jobs for other users so that method doesn't work.

SUBMIT has an addition: TO SAP-SPOOL ... Can you check if it helps? https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abapsubmit_list_options.htm

I've tried a few variations of that but wasn't able to stop the printout.

You can't prevent a program from generating a spool request if this program systematically generates one. Spools requests are removed automatically if "Delete after output" is selected, after they have been sent to the printer or any output device. If you mean that you don't want it to be printed immediately, you may simply unselect "Print now", it will remain in SP01 without being printed, till it's automatically purged after some delay.

First call the function module GET_PRINT_PARAMETERS with no_dialog, mode and immediately parameters:
DATA: ls_print_parameters TYPE pri_params,
      lc_valid_prt_param  TYPE flag.

      CALL FUNCTION 'GET_PRINT_PARAMETERS'
        EXPORTING
          no_dialog              = 'X'
          mode                   = 'BATCH'
          immediately            = ' '
        IMPORTING
          out_parameters         = ls_print_parameters
          valid                  = lv_valid_prt_param
        EXCEPTIONS
          archive_info_not_found = 1
          invalid_print_params   = 2
          invalid_archive_params = 3
          OTHERS                 = 4.

and pass the received structure ls_print_parameters via SPOOL PARAMETERS to SUBMIT call:
SUBMIT (gc_report) TO SAP-SPOOL
  SPOOL PARAMETERS ls_print_parameters
  WITHOUT SPOOL DYNPRO
    ...


Thank you for the suggestion. I've just tried this and tested and unfortunately the spool is still outputted to SP01.

Can you try to to set in the structure ls_print_parameters component pdest to ' '?

Clearing PDEST made it print to a different printer that isn't in my params for some reason. I'll experiment changing different variables to see if I can stop the printout.

Actually it may be working, Just because it's appearing in SP01 doesn't mean it prints immediately. I'll test it with users tomorrow - thanks for your help!

Actually, the fact that it remains in SP01 and doesn't disappear like when I don't set immediately to ' ' is proof that it doesn't print!
